# Comments in Jade/pug

Tags: node.js, pug

I tried making comments in Jade/pug, but the comments render as text in the HTML. This is my code:

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
    body
        / This should be a comment
```

What am I doing something stupid?

Comment: @ppejovic: Thanks, I guess [this page](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade-syntax.html#Comments) is just wrong then.

Comment: @Randomblue that page is in reference to a different library named Jade

Comment: @svachalek: Confusing!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

As written in the [comment documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html), you can either use `//` which will translate to a HTML comment or `//-` which won't be visible in the outputted HTML code.

Comment: I have used `//- test comment` this comment is outputted on source view `ctrl+u` on browser. Have I missed a setting or something ?

Comment: therefore commenting at the very begining of the line comments out the rest of the file...

Comment: @pdelorme no, only if you also indent the rest of the file.

Comment: Updated link for Jade comments documentation:  http://jade-lang.com/reference/comments/

Answer (score 5):

In jade we use **//-** for comment.
If you are trying to comment a block, make sure it should be indented properly like in below example-

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
    body
        //- 
            This should be a comment
            Indent correctly for block content
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!